# Html expressions as lambdas in razor - what's allowed, where is it documented

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I just came across the most awesome feature in Razor I completely missed.

You can define

```
public delegate IHtmlString RazorBlock(Object unknown);
```

and some function

```
public static IHtmlString Foo(RazorBlock block) => block(null);
```

and then call that with a piece of Razor:

```
@(
    Helper.Foo(@<div>some text</div>)
)
```

The inner html is actually what the method `Foo` receives.

I always thought that nesting Razor in lambda's isn't supported. But it is. Razor goes more far than I thought.

My only question:

I found this feature while looking at the samples from DevExtreme's ASP.NET MVC wrappers, and the definition of `RazorBlock` comes from there.

I don't know why the `unknown` parameter is necessary (it is though) and how it can be accessed from the Razor snippet.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why the unknown parameter is necessary (it is though) and how it can be accessed from the Razor snippet.

It's easy to understand by looking at the compiled Razor code (which can be found under %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files).

For example, the following markup:

```
@functions{ 
    public delegate IHtmlString RazorBlock(Object unknown);

    static object Helper(RazorBlock block) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Helper(@<text>
    multi-line
    text
</text>)
```

produces this class:

```
public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic> {
    public delegate IHtmlString RazorBlock(Object unknown);

    static object Helper(RazorBlock block) {
        return null;
    }

    // . . .

    public override void Execute() {
        // . . .

        Write(Helper(item => new System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(__razor_template_writer => {            
            BeginContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 174, 28, true);
            WriteLiteralTo(__razor_template_writer, "\r\n    multi-line\r\n    text\r\n");
            EndContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 174, 28, true);
        })));

        // . . .
    }
}
```

**EDIT**. You can see that `@<text></text>` blocks are transformed into `item => HelperResult` lambdas. And `object => IHtmlString` is the most general delegate signature compatible with that code.